# Statistical meanings of some matrix vector operations

Tags: multivariate-analysis

These questions may be too elementary, but I'm new to statistics and just trying to grasp new concepts, so please be patient with me.

Suppose I have data on a single variable, expressed as ${\bf{y}} = [2 \ 3 \ 6 \ 4]'$, then what does ${\bf{y'y}}$ mean in statistical terms? I know that for two different data vectors that quantity would measure the orthogonality between two variables, but for one single variable I'm not sure what it means.

Suppose I have data for 4 observations on 3 variables and $\bf{X_c}$ is the centered data matrix (subtracting the mean matrix from the data matrix). Also $\bf{D}$ is a diagonal matrix storing the variances. Then what does $\bf{X_c D^{-1/2}}$ mean? I think $\bf{X_c D^{-1}}$ is a way to scale and center the original data to standardize them (is that correct?).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If we define $\mathbf{y} =[y_1\;y_2\;y_3\;y_4\;\cdots\;y_n]$ where $\mathbf{y}$ is a vector of i.i.d (individually and identically distributed) random variables, $$\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{y'}\mathbf{y} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i^2$$ is a sample approximation for the average value of $y^2$, the so called second moment.

Where $Y_i$ has mean 0, (i.e. $E[Y_i]=0$), then $\frac{1}{n-1}\mathbf{y'}\mathbf{y}$ is the sample variance of $Y$.

Where $X_c$ is a univariate random variable of mean 0 and variance $d$, recall that $$\mathrm{var}\bigg(\frac{X_c}{d^{1/2}} \bigg) = \mathrm{var}(X_cd^{-1/2})=1$$
So the equation $\mathbf{X_cD^{-1/2}}$ is simply normalizing the sample variance all 3 variables to 1.